# Android program connects to remote socket via Wifi but not via mobile data

Tags: android, sockets

I've used sockets to connect to my device which listens to port 8000. Also I've configured my router to forward requests on port 8000 to my device.

When android phone is connected to Wifi (both locally and remotely) every thing is fine. Even when my device is connected to personal hotspot of another android phone that uses mobile data, it is OK.

But when my phone directly used mobile data it can not connect to my device.

Any idea about what the problem is?

Comment: You are using the wrong IP? Please show your code

Comment: If I use wrong IP why I connects via wifi even when it's not connects to local network?

Comment: It was a guess. If you use the IP from your local network, that won't work when you disable WiFi. If you use the public IP while on WiFi, some routers ignore that and just use the local one. If you want to test it the port forwarding works, use http://www.canyouseeme.org

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using local IP when connected to WiFi or a local scan or something and you have something like `192.168.1.102` , you'll need to use your public IP, the one your Internet provider assigns you.
Then, that connection will get to your router, if you need specific port connection, your router will have to forward that for you to the target device

Answer (score 0):

In our case the problem has been solved when we replace the IP by domain domain.